# Custom prototype cell not increasing uitableview frame height

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I have `tableview` frame height is 300. I have created one custom `UITableViewCell` subclass for adding to `UITableView` cell. When ever i adding custom cell to `tableview`, `tableview` is not increasing the height of frame. `Tableview` height constant like previous height 300. I want that whenever custom cell is adding the `tableview` height should be increase. How to resolve this?

Comment: @iBhavin, whenever you make edits, make sure your edits are **correct**. What is `UItableciewcell`?

Comment: Sorry for that.Just edited again.

Comment: Prad, please go through the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451) for `UITableView`s.

Comment: It is not the responsibility of the OS to change your table frames according to the cells, it's *your* responsibility. You have to calculate the cumulative height of all your cells (along with all headers/footers, if any), and then set you your table frames accordingly.